# Difference between cat and sudo cat?

Tags: sudo, cat

Can you tell me what the difference is between `cat` and `sudo cat`?

All I know so far is that cat is used for displaying contents of file and concatenation.

Comment: cat is used to read file, sudo is use for super user privileges. so sudo cat mean read the file with super user ( that is root ) privileges.

Comment: Thanx that helped.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For a little humour I would say that cat is an animal and sudo cat is a feline with superpowers. :D

**sudo** is a command that you use to obtain root privileges. root is a special user that manages the machine, and for this he/she has superpowers. For example, if there is a file that only root can see its contents, and you are logged in as a normal user, you can use

```
$ sudo cat name_of_the_file
```

to read it. Also if there is a program that only root can run, like the **reboot** command:

```
$ reboot
warning: must be root!
$ sudo reboot
rebooting...........
```

THE CATCH IS: you must be specially (and manually) assigned by root to have permission to use sudo. The permission is given in a file called /etc/sudoers. In Ubuntu, the first user, the one created during install, is automatically a sudoer. But the subsequent users are not. You have to add them manually to the *group* `sudo` whose members are allowed to use the *command* `sudo`.

By the way, /etc/sudoers is a file that only root can see. So if you do

```
$ cat /etc/sudoers
```

you will not be able to see its contents. But if you do:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
```

you are good.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for explaining cat with an impressive ways. Indeed an amazingly constructed answer. :)

Comment: Surely `sudo cat` is something masquerading as a cat? :oP

Comment: I can't believe nobody has yet posted a link to http://xkcd.com/149/

Comment: Note for all newcomers: Do *not* directly edit `/etc/sudoers`. Any changes to this file must be made via `visudo`. You can grant administrator privilege to users from the System Settings > User Accounts; no need to manually edit `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Will I go to jail for editing /etc/sudoers directly? I really loathe visudo (as I despise vi/vim in general). Didn't know about the sudo group, though, thanks.

Comment: @Henrique The point is you can get locked out of `sudo` if you cause a syntax error in `/etc/sudoers` and then you can't fix it because you can't use `sudo`. `visudo` won't let you save the file if there is a syntax error. Also you can set `visudo` to editor of your choice with `sudo update-alternatives --config editor`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, never knew that. But, still, if you know the guy that owns the root password, you can Always cry for help.

Comment: Just as a personal anecdote, some months after this thread I was locked out of the system for neglecting to use visudo, and I instantly remembered @curusarn 's warning.

Answer (score 6):

**[Cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29)** is a standard unix utiliy and a most frequently used command which concatenate files and print on the standard output.

You may open a terminal (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ATL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) & type `man cat` to know more about the command and its usage.

Further, the difference between `cat` & using `sudo cat`;

- **cat** - Frequently & the standard command in use to print an output
- **sudo cat** - Which prints an output with root privilege. This is mostly needed when a file doesn't have read access for certain user/users but not limited to root user.

Example;

```
-rw------- 2 root root 4096 996 Feb  6 20:39 log.txt
```

Above seen is a file which only a root user (or a user who's within root group) can read/write. In such situation you will need to use `sudo cat filename` to print the output.

Assume it helped you to understand more.!

Answer (score 2):

`cat` is used to read a file; `sudo` is used for super user privileges. So `sudo cat` means read the file with super user (that is, root) privileges.